# Logging to Azure Storage Emulator from on premise Service Fabric application

Tags: c#, .net, azure, logging, azure-service-fabric

I have a named event source as part of my logging:

```
[EventSource(Name = "ExampleEventSource")]
internal sealed class ServiceEventSource : EventSource
```

I can see logs come in when I debug my application in Visual Studio. I now want to deploy my application on premise. **This machine does not use Azure online services at all**.

How can I log events to a locally running Azure Storage Emulator on the premise machine? It seems really easy to enable logging from the Azure portal when dealing with an Azure virtual machine, but with a premise environment this feels extremely over-complicated and lacks some much needed documentation. I tried searching online to find some concrete examples of how this can be done, and [I read the *Collect logs by using Azure Diagnostics* article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-diagnostics-how-to-setup-wad/), but it didn't help and left many questions unanswered. For example, I even find myself stuck here:

> Modify the `template.json` file by performing the following tasks.

What `template.json` file is this article referring to? I am just publishing the solution directly to the remote premise machine from within Visual Studio and, since it is a local project, I presume that may be why there is no `template.json` which was required for the deployment as far as I can tell? Not only that, but I am not sure if this article even truly covers on premise solutions to the same level of logging fruition I am looking for here.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and I hope that whoever decides to help out can sympathize with those of us who want to maintain the same Azure framework for logging, but have it log locally in the emulator so we can use the Azure Explorer tool to view our logs, and I hope they can shed some insights into how this type of logging can be done locally for on-premise environments while maintaining some level of functionality with Visual Studio's deployment abilities.

**Edit**: I tried appending this to the end of my `<ApplicationManifest>` section within `ApplicationManifest.xml` file, but it did nothing:

```
<Diagnostics>
  <ETWSource IsEnabled="true">
    <Destinations>
      <AzureBlob IsEnabled="true" ConnectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" ConnectionStringIsEncrypted="false" ContainerName="traces" />
    </Destinations>
  </ETWSource>
</Diagnostics>
```

**Edit**: I know I can do this manually by using the `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent` NuGet package and subscribing to all of my events, but what is the proper way of logging my traces to file on premise, what is the on-premise Service Fabric-friendly way of achieving this?

```
using (var session = new TraceEventSession("MyRealTimeSession"))
{
    session.Source.Dynamic.All += delegate (TraceEvent data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data);
        // Can add code to flush to Azure tables here...
    };
    var eventSourceGuid = TraceEventProviders.GetEventSourceGuidFromName("ExampleEventSource");
    session.EnableProvider(eventSourceGuid);
    session.Source.Process();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a quickstart example that does this. Have a look [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-management-party-cluster/). You could use [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-management-party-cluster/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventListeners/TableStorageEventListener.cs) class.

The `template.json` they're talking about is the ARM template used to create resources in Azure with.

Comment: Have you ever tried using it? It doesn't seem to be working. Tried to plug it in to my solution with `<Parameter Name="Tracing_StorageAccountConnectionString" Value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />` and `<Parameter Name="Tracing_StorageTableName" Value="traces" />`, instantiated it in my `Program.cs` file, but nothing. `SendEventsAsync` is never called...

Comment: There must be a more integrated way of doing this...aside from not being able to get that class up and running, I would much rather use `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent` to subscribe to events and then log to Azure. However, the problem is also that all of these libraries and classes aren't an integrated solution, whereas I can visually see in the manifest configuration template there is some `<Diagnostics>` support for `<ETWSource>` to on premise locations, so there **must** be a better, more integrated way (fingers crossed).